# Google Api Auth Http Module Error

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm working on my first app ever to use Google Api for Calendar.  I've read the Google examples at: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

The first time I ran the program below it was successful. I allowed my app to access my Google account and the application made a calendar.dat file with the auth info in my app-directory. After I renamed the filed the code was in the auth stopped working. I have already deleted the file entirely and recreated it from scratch, but the error persists.

I do still get the Google authentication page and can still confirm access, after which I get a message that the authentication flow was completed.

This is the code (standard Google example which I fill in with my app details):

```
import gflags
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS

# Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate. This
# sample uses OAuth 2.0, and we set up the OAuth2WebServerFlow with
# the information it needs to authenticate. Note that it is called
# the Web Server Flow, but it can also handle the flow for native
# applications
# The client_id and client_secret are copied from the API Access tab on
# the Google APIs Console
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    user_agent='YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_VERSION')

# To disable the local server feature, uncomment the following line:
# FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False

# If the Credentials don't exist or are invalid, run through the native client
# flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
# Credentials will get written back to a file.
storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
  credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

# Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
# with our good Credentials.
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
# the Google APIs Console
# to get a developerKey for your own application.
service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
       developerKey='YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY')
```

And this is the output:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth? (auth url shortened)

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter 

  --noauth_local_webserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Google Drive\Code\Python\Rooster\calendar.py", line 2, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.6-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Google Drive\Code\Python\Rooster\calendar.py", line 33, in <module>
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\tools.py", line 169, in run
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.0-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 1128, in step2_exchange
    http = httplib2.Http()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Http'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in your run directory you have the file named calendar.py. When Google's httplib2 wants to import a standard calendar module it gets the local one instead. In the local one it executes it to perform the import. But because httplib2 is not yet fully imported the calendar.py code is not working properly.
Just rename the calendar.py to something like myCalendar.py.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had already tried that, as I suspected that to be the problem, however it would not work. I'm coding in Aptana3 and renamed the file in the program. However, after reading your comment and checking the directory it appeared that Aptana generates compiled python files as well, so there was still an extra calendar.py in the directory.

Comment: That's not Aptana but the python I suppose. Python interpreter creates the compiled versions by default.