# error using twilio.rest in python3

Tags: rest, python-3.x, twilio

I'm having an exception occur that I can't understand.

I'm using `twilio.rest` in python 3.4.2 and when I call the twilio api, I'm receiving

> AttributeError:  'module' object has no attribute 'Http'
>   (http2lib?)

I am using
from `twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient`

on the twilio website it shows that that should be the only import that I need, but clearly something isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
i finally fixed this.   when i would install twilio, it would give the message requirement already satisfied for httplib2, six, pytz, pysocks.     i uninstalled twilio, and uninstalled each of those packages, and then re installed [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) (hoping it would re-apply those packages)

it works now!!    i can't really explain why, or perhaps there was a better method, but I wanted to share.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer here.

By chance, is one of the directories in your project is named `twilio`?

That could cause a naming conflict that messes up your import. See this question for a similar situation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863019/5046362